# IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '~.cache/software-center/software-center.log'

Tags: software-center

For some reason Ubuntu Software Center will not open, i have tried reinstalling it however no luck still won't open. Here is the error output i got via a traceback!

```
  File "/usr/bin/software-center", line 40, in <module>
    import softwarecenter.log
  File "/usr/share/software-center/softwarecenter/log.py", line 119, in <module>
    logfile_path, maxBytes=100 * 1000, backupCount=5)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 118, in __init__
    BaseRotatingHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/handlers.py", line 65, in __init__
    logging.FileHandler.__init__(self, filename, mode, encoding, delay)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 897, in __init__
    StreamHandler.__init__(self, self._open())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/logging/__init__.py", line 916, in _open
    stream = open(self.baseFilename, self.mode)
IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error: '/home/shaq/.cache/software-center/software-center.log'
```

Hope someone can help me out with this and help me fix this. This error occured after i installed updates.

I'm using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Try `rm -r ~/.cache/software-center/` in the command line. Also, do you get any errors with `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These three commands worked for me:

```
rm -r ~/.cache/software-center
sudo apt-get remove software-center
sudo apt-get install software-center
```

Comment: When following these instructions, it's very important to avoid accidentally typing a space in the first command after the `~` or the first `/`. If you do, you'll delete all or most of your home directory (including your documents). This command achieves the same thing but it less prone to dangerous typos: `cd ~/.cache; rm -r software-center` Also, you can remove and reinstall in a single step: `sudo apt-get --reinstall install software-center`. To purge systemwide configuration files as well: `sudo apt-get --purge --reinstall install software-center`